# Limiting access to SQS over EC2 Iam role and instance ARN or Instance IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I have general EC2 iam role that I use to join to a domain every new windows EC2 instance that is spun up. One of those instances need to have ability to read SQS, *and only that instance*! I created VPC endpoint for SQS and now I am trying to limit access over condition aws:SourceArn where that is ARN of the EC2 instance or over aws:SourceIp with IP value of private IP of the instance (tried public too, didn't work.

Here is how my SQS access policy looks like.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sqspolicySailpointDevDocument",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/apigateway_sqs"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:123123123123:SailpointSqsDev"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/terraform-AWS-EC2-Domain-Join"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:123123123123:SailpointSqsDev",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:123123123123:instance/i-075b02dfsdfdf435"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Second example for condition

```
"Condition":{
        "IpAddress":{
           "aws:SourceIp":"10.2.32.34"
        }
     }
```

Third example - this one can't pass validation even though it's from Global key context.

> InvalidParameterValue: Value aws:VpcSourceIp for parameter Condition is invalid. Reason: Conditions must be from Global context key list https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html.

```
"Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
           "aws:VpcSourceIp": "10.2.0.0/16"
        }
     }
```

ec2:SourceInstanceARN I can't use because policy allows only Global condition keys.

Worst case scenario, VPC Endpoint has security group and I could limit access from there but it's not nearly ideal solution...

Comment: How about creating a new IAM role with permissions for SQS and let the consuming app call switch-role before accessing SQS. You can limit (by instanceId) which EC2 instance can assume role. Other instances with default role will have no SQS access.

Answer (score 0):

VpcSourceIp is not available for SQS so in order to achieve what I want, one would need vpce (vpc endpoint) for SQS in VPC and then limit access in security group of vpce.